# How do restore printer settings from a backup

Tags: linux, printing, cups

I recently re-installed my system from Mint 12 to Mint 14. Pretty much everything is set as before but I had apparently forgotten about the printers.

In order to avoid resetting all the small details and presets, I wanted to restore the settings from my backup, taken immediately before the re-installing process. So I copied `~/.cups/` and `/etc/cups/` from the backup to the new installation. Then I restarted the Cups daemon, `cupsd`.

When I try to print a paper, all my printers and settings are there and my computer seems to think that the paper prints out fine. The printer, on the other hand, is stuck with the "receiving data" light blinking which eventually leads to the job being deleted from the queue due to an error (with no further information).

What could be the problem here? How does one normally restore CUPS settings?

EDIT: The printer seems to be working fine for all my colleagues; running mac, win and Linux. So it's got to be something with the settings here on my machine.

Comment: Printer manufacturer, model make? What printing system was in use before (when it worked) and now? Did you configure the printer from scratch again? Try restarting the print system.